# Adding image to markdown using WebIDE in GitLab results in broken image - cause and fix?

Tags: image, gitlab, markdown

I am writing to a `README.md` in a git repo hosted on our free tier, self-managed GitLab server. The project behind the repository uses the standard built-in template with a README file also available for project hosted on [gitlab.com](https://www.gitlab.com).

Using the Snipping Tool provided by Windows 10 I copy-pasted a bunch of images inside the document (also to see if it actually works :D). The images were added to the files for committing as well as displayed without any issues inside the Markdown preview window of the GitLab WebIDE. Inside the Markdown view the images were linked (e.g. `![description](image_file.png)`

However after committing the changes I went back to the repository's initial view (list of files plus a preview of the `README.md` file) and saw the following issues:

- The images are displayed as a default icon (for missing image or one that cannot be displayed) followed by a hyperlinked name of the image:

  [image: Sample for broken image]
- The image files are in a weird form similar to
  `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAo0AAAHNCAYAAAB7HUG8AAAgAElEQVR4nOzdeViU9f7/8SeLwyaLgImiB9DSyVKhjohJqZknsUWsjksnt44dNa207Bv67fzUzrnUU2mampmWmvVVWzFNsMKlSEjziJqClgIKhuLoCAnjyPL743Y2GPZlZuD9uC4uh3vuuefj3HMzr/...`

  and cannot be previewed inside the web browser (currently working with Edge so Chrome-based).

While I was inserting the images they got generic names such as `image.png`, `image-1.png` and so on. So I used the WebIDE to rename those (names with spaces).

Checking the URL of the image I've given as an example above I saw that it is `https://GITLAB_SERVER/USER/PROJECT/-/raw/master/fork_project.png`

In addition the file list shows

[image: File as viewed inside file view of repository]

Could it be that the spaces were a problem and through the automatic conversion GitLab got confused? How to I make sure this doesn't happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a [bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/322403) that has been fixed. It seems I need to contact our admins to check on whether they are planning on patching our self-managed free GitLab instance.

Answer (score 3):

Copy-pasting images into GitLab passes the picture to GitLab where it does some magic to auto-write the markdown for you and serves the content. This is how you are able to add images into comments and on issues by just hitting `CTRL+V`.

However, images are just be pasted directly into a Markdown document. This is not the intended use case for Markdown -- some platforms though, like GitLab, perform auto-magic to let you do this.

A standard method for adding images would be to upload the images to the repository and then reference them in the markdown file like so:

Consider the below as an example repository:

```
your_repo:
  - images/
      - image1.png
      - image2.png
  - README.md
```

To add the images into the Markdown of your README.md, you would reference them as such:

`![alternate text](link to image)`

For example, using relative filepaths to the README.md file:

`![Logo](./images/image1.png)`

---

However, with GitLab, you can paste (`CTRL+V`) into the Web IDE while editing a Markdown file and it will automatically upload the image as `image.png` (or similar name) into the repository, writing the embed Markdown for you. You are then free to update the link and rename the image as desired.

It seems that you may want to avoid spaces in the names though. :)

---

*Edit: Learned that the Web IDE does support pasting!*

Comment: I know how to insert. I just decided to try (since it's a feature that more and more platforms support incl. btw Stackoverflow). The preview gave me no indication that it doesn't work. As for the intended way in Markdown - the WebIDE should not allow pasting such content at all then. Also pasting an image adds the file to the repository and links it as you have shown through your examples.

Comment: I see, I just tried it. Learned something new today -- didn't realize it was supported in the WebIDE. However, it seems that it worked fine for me. I was able to paste the image, it auto-added it. Image was viewable in repository and in the document. Then, I was able to rename the image and update the link and commit again, and it was still fine. This may be some sort of bug. I'd definitely avoid spaces in names though! Makes life much easier. Safest bet is probably avoid spaces in general. :)

Comment: See my answer. You probably have a newer version (released/patched less than 9 months ago). Spaces are automatically converted into `_` so that's not an issue as long as this functionality doesn't break. :D

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, we're running on a relatively recent build. Makes sense, thanks for the update and glad you've found the solution! (And thanks for teaching me the WebIDE supports pasting like comments do, haha)